# Install solar floodlight on roof

Tags: installation

Disclaimer: I am very unfamiliar with any terms, so I apologise beforehand for using wrong ones. I'll compensate with pictures.

I have a solar powered outdoor floodlight. It is very similar to this one:

[image: Product Example]

I am thinking of installing it on the (flat concrete) roof by directly stabilising the base pipe part onto the roof's edge. Somehing along these lines:

[image: the plan]

In order to install the pipe onto the edge, what comes to mind is something like this:

[image]

But, these things are only meant to carry the weight of (a portion of) a pipe. Instead, I need them to be able to withstand the upwards torque applied by the device as its outside parts are pulled down by gravity.

Could you recommend me a suitable part to do this, or a better solution altogether?
I measured the pipe perimeter to be 19 cm/0.4 inches.

Help with tags much appreciated.

Comment: Making holes in a watertight roof is not the best way to stay dry. Why not mount it on the brick wall?

Comment: The one in your picture has a mounting base with holes. It's designed so that you drill pilot holes that line up with the ones in the base, then run screws through the mount and into your wall. Maybe describe the issue you're having with using the based designed to mount it by supplying an actual picture of your roof of a size where we can actually see what's going on. That picture A) doesn't seem to be your roof (looks like a random image you picked from the internet), and B) is so tiny we can't tell what's going on, even if it is your actual roof.

Comment: Face bricks are not strong, and holes through the roof invite leaks. My inclination would be to make a clamp, of wood or of metal, to go *over* the edge of the roof, to be tightened with bolts through the inside portion. Sort of a giant-size C-clamp.